# Prove that $B\not\subset f(f^{-1}(B))$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

For a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$, where $B\subset Y$, I need to prove that $B\not\subset f(f^{-1}(B))$, but I'm not necessarily sure how to go about it.  It's easy to show that $f(f^{-1}(B))\subset B$, but that's not too useful here.

Comment: Consider $f~:~\{1\}\to\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: You cannot "prove" this, rather you are looking for a nice counterexample like given by JMoravitz.

Comment: By $B\not\subset f(f^{-1}(B))$, do you mean $B$ is not *always* a subset? There are some functions $f$ and subsets $B$ for which $B \subset f(f^{-1}(B))$.

Comment: Yes, not always a subset is what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Juse take a non-surjective function $f$ from $X$ into $Y$ and a set $B\subset Y$ such that $f(X)\varsubsetneq B$. Then, since $f\bigl(f^{-1}(B)\bigr)\subset f(X)$, $B\varsubsetneq f\bigl(f^{-1}(B)\bigr)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X={\text {{1,2}}}$ and $ Y={\text {{1,2,3}}}$ and  $B={\text {{1,2}}}$.

Define $f:X\to Y$ as$$f(1)=f(2)=1.$$

Note that $$f^{1} (B) ={\text {{1,2}}}$$

$$f(f^{-1} (B)) = {\text {{ 1}} } $$

Thus $$B\not\subset f(f^{-1}(B))$$